# How to use widget by Yii CFrom

Tags: yii, widget, yii-cform

I have a CForm which is instantiate in a controller. Now I need to use some widgets as its element, even by validations and more capabilities.
Who to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations are something that belong into the realm of the injected model. It is not the duty of `CForm`to perform any input validation/sanitization.

As for widgets, see [this part of the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder#specifying-form-elements). Just before the section "Specifying Static Text," there is a whole bunch of informations on how to integrate widgets extending either `CInputWidget` or `CJuiInputWIdget`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't attend it.